# Compressing Undertow server responses

Tags: java, http-compression, undertow

i have a programmatic Undertow server setup. Static content is served by Undertow as well, without a reverse proxy. Java code for Undertow startup looks like this:

```
ResourceManager resourceManager = 
    new FileResourceManager(new File("deploymentDir"), 100);

DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = Servlets.deployment()
      .setResourceManager(resourceManager)
      .setDeploymentName("testDeployment")
      .setContextPath("/");

DeploymentManager manager = Servlets.defaultContainer()
      .addDeployment(servletBuilder);
manager.deploy();

Undertow.Builder builder = Undertow.builder();
builder.addHttpListener(8080, domainName);

PathHandler path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect("/"))
      .addPrefixPath("/", manager.start());

Undertow server = builder.setHandler(path).build();
server.start();
```

I'm wondering how does one gzip server responses in Undertow?

Thanks,
Vitaliy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to look at `GzipContentEncodingTestCase` in Undertow's source to get it to work. One has to create an `EncodingHandler` with appropriate parameters, and then invoke `setNext()` so that to chain it to the `PathHandler`:

```
PathHandler path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect("/"))
    .addPrefixPath("/", manager.start());

final EncodingHandler handler = 
    new EncodingHandler(new ContentEncodingRepository()
      .addEncodingHandler("gzip", 
          new GzipEncodingProvider(), 50,
          Predicates.parse("max-content-size[5]")))
      .setNext(path);

// ...
Undertow server = builder.setHandler(handler).build();
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @siphiuel looks correct to me.

However, EncodingHandler with GZIP encoding can also be created as below:

```
    HttpHandler pathHandler = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect("/"))
        .addPrefixPath("/", exchange -> exchange.getResponseSender().send("echo"));

    HttpHandler encodingHandler = new EncodingHandler.Builder().build(null)
        .wrap(pathHandler);

    Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
        .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
        .setHandler(encodingHandler).build();
    server.start();
```

EncodingHandler provides a HandlerBuilder that by default adds GzipEncodingProvider and DeflateEncodingProvider using default configuration. So your code is not coupled with the constructor and its parameters for creating an EncodingHandler.

Additionally, HandlerBuilder#build returns a HandlerWrapper for fluent HttpHandler wrapping/chaining.

Answer (score 2):

A very interesting link that helped me personally is : [Add compression to Server-Sent events with Undertow](http://streamdata.io/blog/add-compression-server-sent-events-undertow/).
All the parameters used in the EncodingHandler provided by @siphiuel are explained one by one.

Here a quick summary for a gzip compression for example. the parameters of `addEncodingHandler(...)` would be :

- the type (“gzip”)
- the EncodingProvider to apply (Undertow provides implementations for deflate and gzip)
- the priority (multiple providers can be applied, so the priority will be used to choose the provider to apply)
- the predicate to activate the encoding (in @siphiuel's example, only responses with content size > 5 Bytes will be encoded - in the link I shared it's mentioned 5 KB but my tests have proven that it's 5 Bytes).